# How to change the default file format for saving files in Text Mate

Tags: textmate

The default file format for text mate is .txt. I would like to change this to .md for markdown, but I can't figure out where to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open Terminal and enter

```
defaults write com.macromates.textmate OakDefaultLanguage 0A1D9874-B448-11D9-BD50-000D93B6E43C
```

`0A1D9874-B448-11D9-BD50-000D93B6E43C` is the UUID of the Markdown bundle/syntax.

Comment: That totally worked! Thanks. Now how would I find the UUID for the .md extension? That UUID uses .mdown

Comment: I toyed a bit with the TextMate Markdown bundle, and it doesn't seem possible @Lee

Comment: Just figured this out today, if you're still interested: http://brockboland.com/2013/10/markdown-extension/

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind messing with the terminal it can be done. [The instructions can be found here](http://lists.macromates.com/textmate/2006-February/008276.html) via [here](http://wiki.macromates.com/HowTo/SetDefaultFileType). I just tried it and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Unless text mate (which I'm not familiar with) has configured it to be a setting somewhere there really isn't a way to change the default save format.  The only way if such a setting option doesn't exists (which most programs don't have as part of their setup) is to have the source code and make the change there then recompile and reinstall. But unless its open source this wouldn't be a possibility either.